# Convert a matrix from string to integer

Tags: python, string, matrix, type-conversion, integer

I'm trying to change a matrix of numbers from string to integer but it just doesn't work.

```
for element in list:
    for i in element:
        i = int(i)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
This is the whole code:

```
import numpy as np

t_list = []
t_list = np.array(t_list)

list_rains_per_months = [['63', '65', '50', '77', '66', '69'],
 ['65', '65', '67', '50', '54', '58'],
 ['77', '73', '80', '83', '89', '100'],
 ['90', '85', '90', '90', '84', '90'],
 ['129', '113', '120', '135', '117', '130'],
 ['99', '116', '114', '111', '119', '100'],
 ['105', '98', '112', '113', '102', '100'],
 ['131', '120', '111', '141', '130', '126'],
 ['85', '101', '88', '89', '94', '91'],
 ['122', '103', '119', '98', '101', '107'],
 ['121', '101', '104', '121', '115', '104'],
 ['67', '44', '58', '61', '64', '58']]

for element in t_list:
    for i in element:
        i = int(i)
```

I apologize for any mistakes, I'm new to python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing wrong, is that you're not changing the list or any list element: the 'i' inside the loop starts by pointing to each element of the list, then you make it point to something else, but that doesn't affect your list (also, avoid using 'list' as an identifier, it's an existing type, that's asking for trouble).

One way to do it is with list comprehensions. Assuming your matrix is a list of (inner) lists, for example:

```
a_list = [["3", "56", "78"], ["2", "39", "60"], ["87", "9", "71"]]
```

then two nested list comprehensions should do the trick:

```
a_list = [[int(i) for i in inner_list] for inner_list in a_list]
```

This builds a new list, formed by going over your initial list, applying the change you want, *and* saving it a another (or the same) list.

Comment: Thank you for the explenation but mine is a list of lists and your solution I think works only with simple lists, how do I modify it for a matrix?
Edit:
I tried this:
for element in my_list:
    element = [int(i) for i in element]
But it still doesnt work

Comment: My explanation was based on the code you showed, please include an example of your data in the code sample.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me, your solution works, now I understood my mistake

Comment: @marcoboh Please accept the answer if it helped you by selecting the tick mark next to the relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

In numpy you do it that way.

```
import numpy as np

list_rains_per_months = [['63', '65', '50', '77', '66', '69'],
 ['65', '65', '67', '50', '54', '58'],
 ['77', '73', '80', '83', '89', '100'],
 ['90', '85', '90', '90', '84', '90'],
 ['129', '113', '120', '135', '117', '130'],
 ['99', '116', '114', '111', '119', '100'],
 ['105', '98', '112', '113', '102', '100'],
 ['131', '120', '111', '141', '130', '126'],
 ['85', '101', '88', '89', '94', '91'],
 ['122', '103', '119', '98', '101', '107'],
 ['121', '101', '104', '121', '115', '104'],
 ['67', '44', '58', '61', '64', '58']]

list_rains_per_months = np.array(list_rains_per_months)
myfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: int(x))
list_rains_per_months = myfunc(list_rains_per_months)
print(list_rains_per_months)
```

Output

```
[[ 63  65  50  77  66  69]
 [ 65  65  67  50  54  58]
 [ 77  73  80  83  89 100]
 [ 90  85  90  90  84  90]
 [129 113 120 135 117 130]
 [ 99 116 114 111 119 100]
 [105  98 112 113 102 100]
 [131 120 111 141 130 126]
 [ 85 101  88  89  94  91]
 [122 103 119  98 101 107]
 [121 101 104 121 115 104]
 [ 67  44  58  61  64  58]]
```

Comment: I'm using a list of lists so it doesn't work. How do I apply your solution in a matrix?

Comment: Does is helps now?

Comment: I found the solution but thank you for helping me

Comment: Here is the solution for numpy

Answer (score 1):

You could use enumerate object in loops:

```
list = [["12", "10", "0"],
        ["0", "33", "60"]]

for h, i in enumerate(list):
    for j, k in enumerate(i):
        list[h][j] = int(k)
print(list)
```

Comment: I get this error: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You forgot to add the closing `]` to the list.

Comment: It was a problem with the enumerate, but thanks anyway! I got the solution

Comment: I have fixed the bracket, sorry about that. I am also new :S

Answer (score 0):

Could also just `map` each row's values to `int`:

```
for row in list_rains_per_months:
    row[:] = map(int, row)
```

Note that I assign to `row[:]`, i.e., *into* the row and thus into the matrix. If I assigned to `row` instead, I'd have the same problem as you with your `i`: I'd only assign to the variable, not into the row/matrix.